# Creating a web based device config utility

Tags: c#, windows-ce

I want to develop web based configuration utility for WIN CE 6.0 device. This webpage is expected to configure/access/modify device's registry settings, reboot device etc. WIN CE Device has a webserver running on it. I am clueless about how to start.

Suggest some way to modify registry values using webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the source code for the default web admin module.  Fair warning, it's ISAPI, it's near impossible to debug with anything but `MessageBox` calls and it has to be done in C++.  But it is free.

The source is installed with Platform Builder and ends up on your dev machine at

`%WINCEROOT%\PUBLIC\SERVERS\OAK\SAMPLES\HTTP\WEBADMIN`

Another free option would be to create and install a COM object (written in C++,. most likely with ATL) on the target.  Your web pages could then create an instance of that object and use it to interact with the device using the built-in "classic" ASP server.  Installing the COM object on already-deployed devices or devices where you don't create the OS is going to be a large support challenge. Debugging these objects is not fun (though slightly easier than ISAPI if you build a separate test loader app).  Also be aware that the built-in ASP server supports only a very scaled-back subset of ASP 3.0 (which is obsolete to begin with).

All of the web-based device admin we've ever done (and we've been doing it for a decade) has been through the [Padarn Web Server](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/Padarn.aspx), which uses C# following a subset of the IIS object model.  It's a commercial product, so it's not free, and for full disclosure it's a product that we created (because I felt the built-in option is so bad) and sell.

Comment: Can I use remote configuration framework to solve the problem? RCF provides different modules to deal with device. There is one module named "REMOTEUTILS" which enables to create, delete registry values and also reboot the device if requested. You can have look on:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-s/library/ee495105(v=winembedded.60).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee494668(v=winembedded.60).aspx

Comment: Sure.  Those are simply additional examples on how you use ISAPI extensions, written in C++, to interact with the web server.  They are extended examples of the first item above.